# DockerFile does not appear in the docker deployment configuration list

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and the following happens, I only see a single item, which is docker image, when it should also appear, the DockerFile

To summarize, the problem that comes with this missing item is that the deployment of my app, I must do port bidding every time :$

In this list should appear, another item like Dockerfile

[image]
As it appears right here, in an intelliJ configuration where everything is going well.

[image]

**UPDATE** version, intelliJ and Docker

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would probably be helpful to include versions of IntelliJ and the Docker plugin in both these images.

Comment: @AndyShinn thks, Update now.